# Valid value formats for android:padding?

Tags: android

When writing xml files, I know following is working:

```
android:padding="20px"
```

Are there other valid value formats available for `padding`? e.g.

```
android:padding="10px 20px 10px 20px"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `android:paddingLeft , android:paddingRight , android:paddingTop , android:paddingBottom` separately.

Alternatively, since API v17, to properly support bidirectional text (LTR & RTL), change Left to Start and Right to End in all occurances. E.g. `android:paddingLeft` becomes `android:paddingStart`.

You can set padding using coding .  `setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:padding